# JAVA: VarArgs add variables

Tags: java

I have this method:

```
 public static double[] averages(double[]... input) {

   double[] result = new double[input.length];

   for(int i = 0; i< result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = Arrays.stream(input[i]).average().getAsDouble();
   }

   return result;
  }
```

I do not know a priori how many double arrays should I switch to this method. How can I do to add to the method all the variable double [] with a for loop?

In this case I:

```
       ArrayList<double[]> sim=new ArrayList<double[]>();

    arrays.add(new double[]{0.25,0.97,0.47,0.31,0.71});
    arrays.add(new double[]{0.51,0.91,0.88,0.12,0.15});
    arrays.add(new double[]{0.47,0.71,0.42,0.17,0.71});
    arrays.add(new double[]{0.41,0.55,0.53,0.64,0.81});
    arrays.add(new double[]{0.91,0.14,0.71,0.11,0.61});
```

But unfortunately, I do not know arrays double[] before running the program.

Should I go to method averages() 5 double arrays present in ArrayList "sim"

I should get something like this:

```
 averages(arrays.get(0),arrays.get(1),arrays.get(2),arrays.get(3),arrays.get(4))
```

But the content dell'ArrayList "sim" I do not know prior to execution!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's wrong with what you already have? What is it not doing that you don't want it to do?

Comment: I do not know arrays double[] "sim" before running the program. I would like a way to add the various array double[] method averages() in a dynamic execution of the program.

Comment: I read your question several times but I still don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably made a typo, didn't you mean:

```
sim.add(new double[]{0.25,0.97,0.47,0.31,0.71});
```

Would made much more sence.

Then you can call your method as follows:

```
double[] results = averages(sim.toArray(new double[]{}));
```

I didn't try to run it though, the new arrays is there because the method `toArray()` returns `Object[]` and not `T[]` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, I didn't really get your question. But I suppose you want to call your **averages** method like-

```
ArrayList<double[]> sim = new ArrayList<double[]>();

sim.add(averages(new double[]{0.25,0.97,0.47,0.31,0.71}));
sim.add(averages(new double[]{0.51,0.91,0.88,0.12,0.15}));
sim.add(averages(new double[]{0.47,0.71,0.42,0.17,0.71}));
sim.add(averages(new double[]{0.41,0.55,0.53,0.64,0.81}));
sim.add(averages(new double[]{0.91,0.14,0.71,0.11,0.61}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP question is:

> "I have to doSomething() to a list of arrays of doubles but I don't know the size of such list. How can I add arrays of doubles to
>   the list dinamically with a (for) loop?"

If I got it right the first thing you have to understand is the condition at which your loop should end. Since you don't know the size of the list a for loop is not what you need. You should use others loops such as a [while loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) with a well known end condition.

Tell us where those arrays of doubles came from and maybe we can help you more.

For the doSomething() part, e.g. calculate the avarage of every array and put it in another array, assuming everything is ok, the call

```
averages(arrays.get(0),arrays.get(1),arrays.get(2),arrays.get(3),arrays.get(4))
```

should become

```
averages(sim)
```

with the method like this

```
 public static double[] averages(List<double[]> input) {

   double[] result = new double[input.size()];

   int i=0;
   for(double[] doubleArray: input) {
    result[i++] = Arrays.stream(doubleArray).average().getAsDouble();
   }

   return result;
  }
```